# How to test the frontend in Laravel Inertia/React?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, testing, inertiajs, laravel-dusk

I am creating a project using Laravel with Inertia/React, it is working properly, but I can't test the frontend, this is my code:

test/Browser/PostTest.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;

    class ProjectTest extends DuskTestCase
    {
        use DatabaseMigrations;
    
        public function test_project_dashboard()
        {      
           $user = User::factory()->create([
                    'email' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
                ]);
            $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use($user){
                
                $browser->loginAs($user)
                    ->visit('/dashboard')
                    ->assertSee('Dashboard');
            });
        }
    }
```

This is my component: **resources/js/Pages/Dashboard.jsx**

```
.....

export default function Dashboard(props){
    // removed all the js 
    return (
     {/*remove all the html for trying to test*/}
        <div>Dashboard</div>
    );
}
```

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');
```

I removed all the content of the component, I just let the Dashboard, but even in this scenerio the test is not passing

This is the error:

> Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException: Missing required
> parameter for [Route: dusk.logi n] [URI:
> _dusk/login/{userId}/{guard?}] [Missing parameter: userId].

I run first: **php artisan serve**, then **php artisan dusk**, this is my env.dusk.local:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Ojw6k0MzfyfP04G5bzYKrZYyz4eBX4jvQAfzhWTGIq4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_inertia_testing
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
...
....
```

**EDIT**

This is my login page: **resources/js/Pages/Auth/Login.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@/Components/Checkbox';
import GuestLayout from '@/Layouts/GuestLayout';
import InputError from '@/Components/InputError';
import InputLabel from '@/Components/InputLabel';
import PrimaryButton from '@/Components/PrimaryButton';
import TextInput from '@/Components/TextInput';
import { Head, Link, useForm } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';

export default function Login({ status, canResetPassword }) {
    const { data, setData, post, processing, errors, reset } = useForm({
        email: '',
        password: '',
        remember: '',
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            reset('password');
        };
    }, []);

    const onHandleChange = (event) => {
        setData(event.target.name, event.target.type === 'checkbox' ? event.target.checked : event.target.value);
    };

    const submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        post(route('login'));
    };

    return (
        <GuestLayout>
            <Head title="Log in" />

            {status && <div className="mb-4 font-medium text-sm text-green-600">{status}</div>}

            <form onSubmit={submit}>
                <div>
                    <InputLabel forInput="email" value="Email" />

                    <TextInput
                        type="text"
                        name="email"
                        class="email"
                        value={data.email}
                        className="mt-1 block w-full"
                        autoComplete="username"
                        isFocused={true}
                        handleChange={onHandleChange}
                    />

                    <InputError message={errors.email} className="mt-2" />
                </div>

                <div className="mt-4">
                    <InputLabel forInput="password" value="Password" />

                    <TextInput
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        value={data.password}
                        className="mt-1 block w-full"
                        autoComplete="current-password"
                        handleChange={onHandleChange}
                    />

                    <InputError message={errors.password} className="mt-2" />
                </div>

                <div className="block mt-4">
                    <label className="flex items-center">
                        <Checkbox name="remember" value={data.remember} handleChange={onHandleChange} />

                        <span className="ml-2 text-sm text-gray-600">Remember me</span>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div className="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
                    {canResetPassword && (
                        <Link
                            href={route('password.request')}
                            className="underline text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900"
                        >
                            Forgot your password?
                        </Link>
                    )}

                    <PrimaryButton className="ml-4" processing={processing}>
                        Log in
                    </PrimaryButton>
                </div>
            </form>
        </GuestLayout>
    );
}
```

This is my login test:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;

class LoginTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;
    
    public function testLogin()
    {
        $user = User::factory()->create([
            'email' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
        ]);
 
        $this->browse(function ($browser) use ($user) {
            $browser->visit('/login')
                    ->type('email', $user->email)
                    ->type('password', 'password')
                    ->press('Login')
                    ->assertPathIs('/dashboard');
        });
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

> Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element:
> Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body
> email"}

What can I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get started, let's write a test that verifies we can log into your application. You need to quard with login and pass parameters

```
public function test_project_dashboard()
{      
         $user = User::factory()->create([
            'email' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
        ]);
 
        $this->browse(function ($browser) use ($user) {
            $browser->visit('/login')
                    ->type('email', $user->email)
                    ->type('password', 'password')
                    ->press('Login')
                    ->assertPathIs('/dashboard');
        });
}
```

Comment: thank you for responding: after I tried what you mentioned, now I have this error:
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body email"}. it looks like the error happens due to inertiajs